# Does Apache-Solr have a timeout if Solr is not reachable?

Tags: php, solr

I am using solr-php-client https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/

Does it have a timeout option that I can manually set?
Because whenever Solr (webSolr) is unreachable, I'm having problems
Even if the `$solr->search()` call is within a Try Catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

always `PING` solr server before any `insert/select/update/delete` request

```
 $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service($hostname, $portname,$core);

 if(!$solr->ping())
 {
    echo "server not responding";
    exit;
 }

 $solr->search($basicQuery, $start_limit,$end_limit,$params);
```

Comment: So the **ping** function has a timeout? and of how much approx?

Comment: default it is set to 2s. if u want to customise it, pass as parameter with ping functions in second. like.. for 30 second `!$solr->ping(30)`